# 4x7 grid of checkboxes using Flet

Tags: flet

How do you make a 4 (rows) by 7 (columns) of checkboxes using Flet?  I can get all 28 checkboxes to be displayed, but can't get them into 4 rows of 7.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the solution to my question:

```
import flet as ft

def main(page):
    DaysOfWeek = ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
    checkboxes=[]
    for j in range(0,4):
        def boxes(count):
            boxes = []
            for i in range(0,7):
                boxes.append(ft.Checkbox(label=DaysOfWeek[i]))

                checkboxes.append(boxes)

            return boxes


        row2 = ft.Row(spacing=30, controls=boxes(7))
        page.add(row2)

        
ft.app(target=main)
```